# Error Ocurred while giving permission to a user group in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I have created a new module in OpenERP. I have created two user groups, manager and user. Next I want give permission to the manager, that he needs to access only the details of his own projects. I have added the below code in a security XML file.

```
<record id="property_rule_mat_mgmt_manager" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Material Manage Rule</field>
            <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_project_project"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('project_id.members','=',user.id),('project_id.user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('group_mat_mgmt_manager')), (4,ref('group_mat_mgmt_user'))]"/>
        </record>
```

but I got an error like this

> Server Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openerp-web\addons\web\session.py", line 91, in
>   send
>       return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\netsvc.py", line
>   361, in dispatch_rpc
>       result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\service\web_services.py",
>   line 582, in dispatch
>       security.check(db,uid,passwd)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\service\security.py",
>   line 40, in check
>       pool = pooler.get_pool(db)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\pooler.py", line 50, in
>   get_pool
>       return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\pooler.py", line 33, in
>   get_db_and_pool
>       registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, pooljobs)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\registry.py",
>   line 154, in get
>       update_module, pooljobs)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\registry.py",
>   line 176, in new
>       openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py",
>   line 329, in load_modules
>       processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py",
>   line 244, in load_marked_modules
>       loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py",
>   line 180, in load_module_graph
>       load_data(module_name, idref, mode)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py",
>   line 78, in 
>       load_data = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='data')   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py",
>   line 125, in _load_data
>       tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line
>   955, in convert_xml_import
>       obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line
>   848, in parse
>       self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line
>   806, in _tag_record
>       f_val = self.id_get(cr, f_ref)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line
>   825, in id_get
>       res = self.model_id_get(cr, id_str)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line
>   834, in model_id_get
>       return model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, self.uid, mod, id_str)   File
>   "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\cache.py", line
>   18, in lookup
>       r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\cache.py", line
>   46, in lookup
>       value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py",
>   line 857, in get_object_reference
>       data_id = self._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\cache.py", line
>   18, in lookup
>       r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\cache.py", line
>   46, in lookup
>       value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py",
>   line 850, in _get_id
>       raise ValueError('No such external ID currently defined in the system: %s.%s' % (module, xml_id)) ValueError: No such external ID
>   currently defined in the system: mat_mgmt.model_project_project

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line with

`<field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_project_project"/>` to

```
<field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
```

Comment: I replaced the line but now I got another error ValueError: Invalid field 'project_id.members' in domain expression

Comment: so remove project_id.member and used members

Comment: <field name="domain_force">['|',('members','in',[user.id]),('project_id.user_id','=',user.id)]</field> like this dear!!

Comment: I got an error like this ValueError: Invalid field 'project_id.user_id'

Comment: <field name="domain_force">['|',('members','in',[user.id]),('user_id','=',us‌​er.id)]</field>  use this

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else if finding it difficult to find the correct model id, you can do the following.

- Activate the developer mode
- Go to Settings | Technical | Database Structure | Models
- Find and select the model that you want
- At the drop down at the top where it says "Debug view#", select "View Log (perm read)"

You will see the XML ID there